# Facebook Photo Upload Problems

Tags: facebook, photos

I have a Motorola Droid, rooted, running Cyanogen Mod 6.1.2.  Been having some issues with uploading photos to Facebook.  The upload takes forever and, if I let it go all the way through, it will normally get to 100% but will never say that the photo was uploaded successfully.  Sometimes the photo will actually make it, but I can't clear the upload status notification.  Ideas?

Comment: Did you have any trouble on a stock ROM?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your phone, the photo upload feature for Facebook just doesn't work well.  I also have a Moto DROID v1 running the stock 2.2.2 version of Android.  Over the air uploads are terribly unreliable.  The app often crashes, hangs at 0%, hangs at 100%, and very rarely, completes the upload.  On a WiFi connection the uploads are slightly more reliable, but still prone to error.

I suspect that the app is expecting to be able to do a complete upload at once over a single connection.  When working over the air, your phone might drop out long enough to drop the network session.  The app isn't handling that well.